# How to find the GUID of LEAP Office Accounting Client for 64-Bit Operating Systems and use it for deleting a registry key?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have created a .cmd script that runs an uninstall on a specific piece of software as follows:

```
Title LEAP Office Accounting Client for 64-Bit Operating Systems
Echo LEAP Office Accounting Client for 64-Bit Operating Systems
WMIC Product Where "Name='LEAP Office Accounting Client for 64-Bit Operating Systems'" Call Uninstall /NoInteractive
```

This results in a remaining entry in the uninstall control panel and I have linked this to a registry key still remaining after the uninstall is called:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\InstallShield_{7BF4C2E2-96B9-4E84-B0FC-0C084B4068F1}

What can I add to my script, so it ensures this is removed either via the uninstall command or a separate delete command?

The last part of the registry key `{7BF4C2E2-96B9-4E84-B0FC-0C084B4068F1}` is unique (GUID). So I would need to find the correct registry key each time as the script is made to remove this software more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Since `{7BF4C2E2-96B9-4E84-B0FC-0C084B4068F1}` is dynamic and will change based on installation, we can use `/s /f "Key value data"` to search the `\Uninstall\` directory and its sub-keys for the key-values based on the value data of the `DisplayName`. To do this we can use a `for` statement along with `REG QUERY` to set a string with the path of the sub-directory the key belongs to.

To remove a key, we will want to use `REG DELETE` - `reg delete /?`

The Parameter `/f` will remove the entry without asking for confirmation.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=2 delims={}" %%a in ('
    REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s /f "Put your programs DisplayName's value here"
') do REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{%%a}" /f

pause
```

This script will remove your key based off the value of `DisplayName`. You will want to search your registry for this value and insert it in the script. Be sure to run this script as administrator.

Comment: This command doesn't work, Nothing is removed and when I attempt to search just using 
`REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s /f "LEAP Office Accounting Client for 64-Bit Operating Systems"` 

There are no results

Comment: @user10073459 If there are no results then it does not exist or you don't have the correct name. It's very case sensitive. Try putting just `LEAP Office Accounting Client`

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :del_uninstall_key "LEAP Office Accounting Client for 64-Bit Operating Systems"

exit /b

:del_uninstall_key
setlocal
set "key="

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('
    reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
    /s /f "%~1"
    ^|find "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
') do if not defined key set "key=%%~A"

if not defined key (
    >&2 echo Reg key not found.
    exit /b 1
)

reg delete "%key%" /f
exit /b
```

The label `:del_uninstall_key` is called with the *displayname* value.
`reg query` searches for the value and gets the 1st line of the
returned text which is expected to be the key. Use of `find`
limits the returned value to those with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

If the variable `key` is defined, the `reg delete` command will execute.

Use `for /?`, `reg /?` and `exit /?` for command help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea, based of the assumption that you can also determine the unique GUID from the same `Win32_Product` result.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "GUID="
Set "RKEY=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
Set "PROD=LEAP Office Accounting Client for 64-Bit Operating Systems"

For /F "Tokens=2Delims==}" %%A In ('WMIC Product Where "Name='%PROD%'" Get IdentifyingNumber /Value 2^>Nul') Do Set "GUID=%%A}"
If Not Defined GUID Exit /B
WMIC Product Where "Name='%PROD%'" Call Uninstall
Reg Delete "%RKEY%\InstallShield_%GUID%" /F>Nul
```

*I do think however that if you're accessing the registry, you could probably uninstall the software using the `UnistallString` value data from that location.
You may even be able to parse the data for the switches it uses and optionally add you own to make the process less interactive.*

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I want although for some reason no registry Key is found, when I check regedit I can find the exact Key and when I try to do a reg query for the exact same Key it finds no entries.

Comparing the registry to `Reg Query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\` 
I find that InstallShield_{7BF4C2E2-96B9-4E84-B0FC-0C084B4068F1} is shown in the registry but not the CMD?

Comment: @user10073459, if you are not Running the script as Administrator, you will not have access to the key for its removal!

Comment: The script was being run as admin, so I'm stumped as to why it wasn't locating the key...

Comment: @user10073459, the first thing I'd suggest is to verify that the first loop is returning the correct GUID, and that it matches the registry key. You can easily do that by removing the uninstall line, and changing the last line to, `Echo Reg Delete "%RKEY%\InstallShield_%GUID%" /F^>Nul`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the issue avoiding the registry key removal

```
@Echo Off
Set "GUID="
Set "PROD=LEAP Office Accounting Client for 64-Bit Operating Systems"

For /F "Tokens=2Delims==}" %%A In ('WMIC Product Where "Name='%PROD%'" Get 
IdentifyingNumber /Value 2^>Nul') Do Set "GUID=%%A}"
If Not Defined GUID Exit /B
WMIC Product Where "Name='%PROD%'">

"C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation 
Information\%GUID%\setup.exe" /m:uninstall
```

Running this installer correctly removes the key unlike the WMIC command although it does prompt the user. Is it possible to run the uninstall silently? I have attempted to add `/quiet` but that didn't work.